# Do "gateway tests" work?

Tags: undergraduate-education

Here is an overview of the practice of "gateway testing", which explains it much better than I could:

https://sites.lsa.umich.edu/michigan-math-in-action/2015/09/24/25-years-gateway-testing-at-michigan/

But for completeness I'll quote the basic idea:

> What’s a gateway test? Our definition is that it is a test of basic skills. These may be skills that are prerequisite for success in a course, or may be skills which every student in a course should develop.... However, while these skills are intrinsic to or essential for success in the courses, they are not our educational focus. Our courses focus on conceptual understanding... Our gateway tests are 7 or 10 question tests, administered on-line... which students may take multiple times and which they must complete with almost no errors to pass.... Students may practice the tests as many times as they like, but to get credit for having passed the test they must take the test in a proctored lab where their identity is verified and where they are not allowed to use outside resources.... completion of the test is not a part of the students’ course averages; instead, any student who doesn’t pass a gateway by the specified deadline... has her/his final grade reduced by 1/3 to a full letter grade at the end of the semester.

The above link includes a bit of evidence that the gateway tests work at Michigan, at least that they correlate with students learning the gateway material.  But I would like to know if any more serious data analysis has been done on gateway tests (anywhere)?  In particular, I would like to know whether implementing gateway tests has a positive effect on *overall* student performance.

Comment: I did some TAing for a professor who was practising something very similar and it worked rather well in my experience. I do not have any more substantiated evidence, however. Should this question not get an answer in due time, I will ask him whether he knows something (ping me in case I forget).

Comment: I think it would be interesting to ask specifically whether the WeBWorK people (which I suspect UMich uses for this) have some data on this.

Comment: I have done something similar to this in the past in my freshman mechanics course. Topics included entry skills (conversions and proportionalities) and skills taught in the course (vector addition). I called them MOB tests, for "mastery of the basics." It was online, and they could retry as many times as they wished. I didn't have resources available to make it proctored. I discontinued it because many students seemed to be copying answers from someone else, and one way I could tell that was happening was that they couldn't do the same stuff on exams.

Comment: @kcrisman: The link states that they did use WebWork in their final implementation. However, I doubt that anyone but the profs running the course would have data, since there are probably privacy laws that apply -- unless, perhaps, the data were anonymized somehow?

Comment: Regardless of who has the webwork data (and I expect it would be the UMich sysadmins, since I suspect they are running their own webwork server rather than using the MAA's hosted version), I don't think it would answer the question.  I want to know about the effect of gateway tests on overall performance in the class, e.g. on final exams, not just about the performance of students on the gateway tests themselves.

Comment: I have done a gateway exam (mostly trigonometry) in a Calculus class and anecdotally it definitely raises the quality of the course -- setting "prerequisite expectations" early and clearly does a lot for the classroom environment. But this isn't data. I hope to see answers posted to this question someday.

Comment: Have you tried looking up references 2, 5, and 6 from the article?

Comment: @BenCrowell No; I would have to get them from ILL, and the context of their citations in the text didn't make them sound likely to contain the kind of data I want. But if I don't get any answers here, I may track them down for want of anything better.

Comment: I teach at Michigan, including I taught Applied Linear Algebra which instituted a Gateway on row reduction and other matrix operations while I was there. My post-gateway syllabus has an extra week of material in it, because I spend so much less time on these basics. But I don't have the sort of formal data you want.

Comment: I had a similar try, having a few basic questions in front of a final exam that determined a multiplicative coefficient on the grade. I cannot assess the effect unfortunately, but I must say that it was more of a gateway than only downgrading by 1/3: below a certain threshold, I gave failing grades whatever the other answers where. This seems more consistent with the idea that the material is mandatory.

Comment: To really answer this question I think you'd need a controlled study with random assignment:  half of all students are placed in sections with a gateway test requirement, and half are placed in sections without.  You'd also have to control somehow for different instructors.  I doubt such a study has been done.

Comment: Have you followed up on the references in the linked article (e.g., in PRIMUS)?

Comment: What is the difference between gateway test and placement test? Failure in the former does not prevent one to take the course, failure in the latter does?

Comment: @RustyCore A placement test covers prerequisites and is used to determine if a student may take a course.  A gateway test covers specific course learning outcomes (e.g., row reduction in a linear algebra course), and must be repeated until mastery (to pass the course).

Comment: @Matthew Leingang, why would you give students extra tests if they have to pass the course final anyway? Are they given in place of seminars?

Comment: @RustyCore did you read the link given in the question?

Answer (score 4):

I apologize for not leaving this as a comment, but being new to this StackExchange I will reply in the way in which I am able.

I do not have the hard data you are seeking, but I'll share my personal experience.

I am a math PhD student, and each semester I teach a 100 level math course (in our department these are (primarily) retreads of things the students should have learned in high school).  Examples include Algebra, trigonometry and Pre-Calculus.  Incoming students are placed in these courses based on a placement test taken during orientation (provided they do not have credit for AP Calculus, or transfer credits from a community college, etc.)

However, many students still struggle with basic things like exponent rules, fraction addition, and knowing the 'legal' algebraic moves they may make to solve an equation.  So in this sense I'm not sure how useful our placement exams are.

Personally, I address this issue in the following way.  If I'm about to teach something, for example an introduction to exponential  functions, I will do something like the following:

1. Motivate with some discrete examples
2. Give the students problems to try that require a good understanding of exponent rules
3. circulate and give differentiated help
4. work thorough the problem while explaining my reasoning
5. tell the students that if they struggled with exponent rules that that is something they are assumed to know, so it is beyond the scope of the lecture
6. direct them to resources for additional practice and offer to help in office hours
7. give a general algorithm for solving similar problems
8. give word problems to try and help students to develop basic number sense

   I do this for two reasons.  First, is that these courses are prerequisites for others in the department, and the instructors of those courses will assume a certain set of material has been covered.  Second, I want my students to take ownership of the learning process.  I will do everything reasonable to help them to succeed, but I also make them earn their success.  To use a trite saying: I will lead them to water, but I will not force said water down their throats.

Having taught high school before university, I find that many students in high school, and indeed in the first couple years of college, have been conditioned to think that it is the instructors job to make them pass.  I do my best to break them of this notion.

While it is true that I occasionally get bad reviews from individual students, and indeed more students fail my course (roughly 30-40% are likely to fail this semester) than might be ideal to pass them on when they haven't demonstrated some level of mastery does no one favors.  This is how we have students in multivariate calculus that still cannot correctly do basic algebra.