# How should mathematics tests be designed?

Tags: exams, critical-thinking

I am speaking about high school mathematics .
Students have attended a mathematics course . By the end thereof ,  students are supposed to be able to:

1. find the limit of a real function f as “x” approaches to a given “a” and write the equations of vertical , horizontal and oblique asymptotes to the function’s curve  (but not curved asymptotes)
2. use the squeeze theorem to find some limits
3. find the derivative of a real function and deduce whether the function is monotonic or not  (depending on the sign of the derivative)
4. write the equation of the tangent straight line to a curve at a given point
5. determine the number of the solutions to an equation of the form f(x) = m (m is a real number) using the mean value theorem
6. determine whether a real function is continuous or not at a given point
7. draw the curve of a given function in an orthogonal system
8. decide whether  a sequence is monotonic or not
9. decide whether a sequence is an arithmetic one , a geometric one , or neither
10. calculate the limit of a recursive sequence (of the form un+1 = f(un) )
11. decide whether two sequences  are adjacent or not

- Students are familiar with the following functions: the square root function , the absolute value function , exponential and logarithmic functions , polynomial functions , and trigonometric functions

12. decide whether three vectors are coplanar or not
13. calculate the dot product of two vectors
14. write a cartesian equation of a plane , sphere , cone and cylinder
15. write a parametric equation of a straight line , a half line , a line segment
16. find the barycenter of n weighted points
17. solve a system of three linear equations
18. write the algebraic, rectangular and exponential forms of a complex number
19. solve a second degree equation with complex variables  and/or coefficients
20. describe each of these geometrical transformations (rotation , homothety
    , and translation ) using complex numbers

- Those are NOT all the skills which the students must have developed throughout  the course.

After the course have ended and the students have mastered the skills above,  they are supposed to take a 3 hours test which is “the final exam for the entire course” .

The questions is :
How the test is supposed to be designed?

The problems from which the test is composed , should they be routine, typical ones which mimic the ones in the students’ textbooks?
Or new ones which need a lot of thinking and imagination, yet require the same knowledge provided by the students’ textbook?

Some students who are accurate and do not make “arithmetic error” would find no difficulty solving any of the routine problems they are used to such as

1. Given a function f defined on a set I : the students would find the limits of the function , the derivative thereof, determine the number of solutions to the equation f(x)=0, draw the graph of the function in an orthogonal system
2. Given two complex numbers , the students would write both numbers in the exponential form , found  both the exponential and algebraic form of their product , deduce the trigonometric ratios of an angle (most probably , the argument of the product )
   Etc.

However, what benefit did such a test give? Did the test reflect enough the mathematical thinking of the students who took it?

Would it be reasonable if ,for instance, out  of 100 students , 10 students took a perfect score ? It is possible that there exists 10 math “geniuses” within a group of 100?

I hope the question became clearer after this edit.If still not clear, please notify in the comments.

Please note that the test is NOT a multiple choice test.

Comment: I disagree with your idea that only one student should achieve a perfect score. The goal of a test is not to trip up students it is to test how well they have understood and can apply the material learned. A good teacher should have been able to clarify the material in such a way that multiple students have achieved such clarity as to achieve a perfect or near perfect score.

Comment: @Burt Acheiving a high score  is a mutual achievement (between the teacher who “clarified” the material and the student ). However , I see that acheiving a perfect score must be the student’s achievement and only his

Comment: The questions of the test must asses the students’ own skills and abilities . The teacher’s job is to “clarify the material” . However , it is the student’s job to improve his /her mathematical tools and critical thinking .

Comment: The results must reflect these three factors :

1- How successful the teacher was in delivering the material

2- How well the students studied 

3- How much have the students developed their own mathematical abilities

Comment: @Burt It is all about “how well the can apply the material learned” I think that even if all students understand the material , there still exist students who are better at applying the material than their peers. The test must also discover these students . What I meant is that one student at most most take the perfect score (or three in the worst cases), the others can take 95/100, but not 100/100

Comment: I agree that not all students should be achieving a perfect score, and that would be a sign of a test that was too easy and not displaying any critical thinking. I simply feel that the number of students achieving a perfect or near perfect score should be more than one.

Comment: FYI, these scores look like scores on a [gateway test](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/12285/745) to me. As for your several questions, they seem highly dependent on your specific local circumstances. If I were requested to provide advice (say, as an external math consultant), then I would need to have a fairly complete idea of texts used, syllabi followed, samples of in-class short quizzes and hour tests from several previous teachers of the course, the purpose of the course $(\%$ of students is it a prerequisite for further study, $\%$ of students is it a terminal course), etc.

Comment: This really isn't a new topic, debate.  Huge literature on testing design and objectives.

Comment: It's important to differentiate performance measurement versus differentiation within the cohort.  Too many people think the overall objective is/should be ranking.  This means a poorly taught class, for example, still gets curved to pass people.  However, more sophisticated design, actually has a specific standard and then verifies if people meet it.  Think about carrier landings for instance.  They don't curve those.

Comment: In education, you have to do larger studies or year to year comparisons and the like.  But you can still certainly come up with a performance standard.  It won't be like a Euclid proof perfect, but will be way better than just curving.  Like a war plan or an NPV.  The effort to make it teaches you thinks about your topic.

Comment: "One student at most would be considered “outstanding”" — grading on a curve sucks, agreed with guest above.

Comment: The idea that only one student should achieve perfect score seems rather outlandish to me. Especially at the high school level, where many of the problems taught are routine exercises, there should be (in my personal experience, though of course this could vary for different people) many students who would be perfectly capable of handling the material well enough to achieve perfect score. In fact, for some classes most students should be able to achieve perfect score without much trouble, and the most common reason some of them do not is some kind of easy, careless computational error.

Comment: @YiFan You have pointed at the issue I raise  “routine exercises”. I think that the problems in tests shouldn’t be that routine .

Comment: The issue is  that the  test problems are “routine exercises” . Thus, any student who has tried to  solve  a few of these typical problems and doesn’t make “careless computational error” would take a perfect ,or near perfect , score .

Comment: Let me clarify , not all people comprehend mathematics with the same “deepness” . Some students tend to have a deeper comprehension of the mathematical concepts than their peers , others think nothing of mathematics but finding the limit at a , and how to “get rid “ of an indeterminate form while finding the limit.

Comment: I also see that this applies to teachers. Not all teachers have the same “depth” in understanding math. Not all teachers show the same proffesionality while teaching math or writing a solution to a problem. Another example , some students/ teachers would insert the implication symbol  at every moment without thinking if this symbol makes any sense within the context within which it was inserted. Such “routine” tests show nothing about the depth of students’ understanding .

Comment: Even for routine exercises, it is unusual for large cohorts to get a several question test, perfect.  Remember that they are "routine" in the sense of non-tricky or complicated, but are still a new topic for the trainee.

Comment: I think not. Let’s consider the example I used in the question’s post . If students were taught throught  a long period of time ( a year for instance) , how to calculate limits and how to find derivatives , and have  caluclated dozens of limits  ,throughout that period of time,have faced dozens of indeterminate forms, and have found the derivatives of dozens of functions after memorizing by hard the deriviatives of the basic functions and the rules of derivation (of composite functions for example).

Comment: @guest The students were then asked ,in the test, to find the deriviative of a function f defined on I , to calculate the limits therof at (...) , to prove there exists n solutions and only n to the equation f(x) = 0 (a cliché which they memorize by hard) , and to draw the curve of the function in an orthogonal system. What kind of mental effort the students are supposed to exert while solving to the previous problem ? The students already know what steps they must follow in order to solve the problem , they only need to be careful not to make “careless computational error”.

Comment: Maybe I was mistaken when I said “one student at most must take a perfect score” , “one student at most would be considered outstanding”.  It is still “somehow” reasonable if three or four students scored perfect and were considered very good , but not more.

Comment: I am relatively new to SE. Please tell me if I have violated the rules of the community. Is my question clear enough ? Does it need more clarification? It is considered “opinion-based” ? I ask this as I haven’t received any answers until the moment.

Comment: I am thinking about why you haven't gotten answers. I would like to suggest that you put forth a premise (that the distribution of scores indicate that there is something wrong with the test) and then asked how to fix the test.  The problem seems to be that people don't agree with your premise.  Perhaps you should first ask about your premise in a question.

Comment: *I haven’t received any answers* --- For me the problem in trying to address this is that I know nothing about the context of the "test". For example, you said "3 hours". The last 3 hour tests I have experience with were **final exams** for an entire course (not just a "test"), and this was back in the 1970s. Throughout the 1980s, 1990s, 2000s all the high-schools/colleges/universities I've taught at (10, unless I've miscounted) had final exams that were a maximum of 2 hours. I suspect you're not in the U.S., and furthermore, what you mean by "test" is not what many here have experience with.

Comment: The reason I did not post an answer is that I have no idea what the question is. If the question is, as you titled it, "How should mathematics tests be designed," then it is too broad for an SE site. If it is not that, then spending effort on removing unnecessary paragraphs, asides, and ideas from your question would improve it significantly. Identifying which premises you are asking about, and which ones you are not willing to discuss, and distinguishing those clearly, would improve the question as well.

Comment: I think the question is too narrow.  Suggest broadening it to be "how to teach mathematics".  ;-)

Comment: 1.  Even routine questions are somewhat new to the people. I mean, they didn't know them the year before!  2. Arithmetic errors or algebra errors are not trivial.  Are an important factor in doing good work, processing mathematics.  3.  In addition, remember the students are under pressure.  4.  Students are often not well drilled on "routine" problems.

Comment: I'm sure you could construct some artificial example to pass your wickets.  But I doubt that you would get 20% perfect scores with most trials of your case.  For a tactical example, consider a final exam of medium level students (say level one state uni, already a level over what most here teach at) in ODEs, using the text by Speigel.  It has HW in 3 grades. A (routine), C (hard) and B (in between, usually more multi-step).  I don't think you'd get 20% perfect scores for a 15 question test (5 per hour) drawn from the A/B bank.  Not even if all from the A bank.  I will make it Bayesian and bet.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "test."  Different tests have different objectives.  See [this Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Educational_assessment#Placement,_formative,_summative_and_diagnostic).  Is the test you are thinking of a placement test, a formative test, a summative test, or a diagnostic test?

Comment: Here's the thing, there already is a test like this for Math majors. We gave it to our exiting majors to check on their progress. Sometimes we got 5 with a perfect score. It was useful data, because, often we got just one or none with the perfect score. Yes it just tests mostly the mindless routine stuff, but that stuff matters. That said, I do think we'd do better to have tests with a lot more uncertainty. Some outlier questions would help to discern whether or not some math departments are teaching more than just the drill part of math that some of us love so much to champion...

Comment: You just edited your post to remove three words.  Why didn't you edit it to clarify your post?  What kind of test are you interested in?  I'm voting to close your post as unclear.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche The test can be considered a summative one.

Comment: (I've retracted my close vote.)

Comment: There are a lot of comments and I may have missed the answer to this - if I did I apologize.  Your question has the label "gifted students".  I am wondering if this is because all the students in the class are gifted or are you wondering how to identify the gifted students using your test.

Comment: @AmyB Frankly speaking , I have put  this label for two reasons : a) I felt that two tags/labels are not enough , I thus had to add a third one. However , I failed to find another suitable tag , so I chose to use the “gifted students” tag, as it is the “most” suitable one. This is the main reason. b) Because I see that among the multiple purposes of the tests (the final exam for the entire course) is to identify the gifted students.

Answer (score 4):

> "The problems from which the test is composed , should they be
> routine, typical ones which mimic the ones in the students’ textbooks?
> Or new ones which need a lot of thinking and imagination, yet require
> the same knowledge provided by the text?"

I recommend to go with the "routine" questions.  (Scare quotes intentional!)  (1) Don't underestimate the difficulty of "routine" to many students.  (1.5) ESPECIALLY under test conditions.  (2.)  You're covering a lot of material and some of it will be several months old.  (3.)  There is a value to the routine questions.  (4.) Separating the stars (small minority) from the above average (larger amount, but still a minority) should not replace the objective of measuring basic competency for the majority of the kids.  (4.5) And you'll get it anyway, since in a 3 hour test, there's room for stumbles.  It won't be so basic that the top 3 of 30 can't be differentiated from the next 6.  They'll separate.  Look at the literature on psychrometrics.  Look at "easy" tests like SAT-M.

In fact, there's a real danger of running acrux if your questions are too tricky and non routine.  You're basically testing problem solving savvy more than mastery of the curriculum and even the sharpies can just get unlucky about figuring out some Euler trick or the like under exam conditions.  I think a routine 20 question test (one per objective) will be fine.

Oh...and a lot of those objectives are pretty conceptual.  Not sure I agree with so much stress on that.  It is important to have kids that can do manipulations to support what they will need in physics and engineering homeworks.  It's not awful and there are some tactical objectives.  And maybe it's just written that way to look fancy and the questions are more recognizable.  Not a strong objection, just a little hair on my neck.  ;-)

---

It's interesting to look at your MSE question, where you ask about making silly mistakes.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3796357/how-can-i-prevent-silly-frustrating-mistakes-while-solving-math-problems

It's one thing if you just want hard questions.  But hard questions (concept emphasis) when you don't have mastery of the basics?  Sorry, that is a big problem.  You NEED to have automaticity of the basics if you are going to do advanced math or physics or engineering (even decent undergrad level homework, especially junior year on, let alone research).

Look at Olympic level gymnasts (I worked out with some back in the day).  They spent their time working on very hard D-level and above skills (full twisting double backs and such).  Remember asking one how to progress and he told me...you need to be solid on your basics...you don't have a 30 second handstand, you don't have good circles on horse, and your backhandspring has no distance.

The movie The Karate Kid is an exaggeration of this concept, but it really is true in spirt in martial arts.  Well, at least boxing.  You need to have basic stance and protection and the like down solid.  And jab, jab, jab.  Yeah, you'll want those fancy combinations.  But learn to jab, baby.  It will keep you safe.

Here is what Richard Feynman advised CALTECH students regarding mathematics (section 1-3 of Feynman Lectures Physics):

So, this guy comes into my office and asks me to try to make everything straight that I taught him, and this is the best I can do. The problem is to try to explain the stuff that was being taught. So I start, now, with the review. I would tell this guy, “The first thing you must learn is the mathematics. And that involves, first, calculus. And in calculus, differentiation.”

Now, mathematics is a beautiful subject, and has its ins and outs, too, but we’re trying to figure out what the minimum amount we have to learn for physics purposes are. So the attitude that’s taken here is a “disrespectful” one towards the mathematics, for sheer efficiency only; I’m not trying to undo mathematics.

What we have to do is to learn to differentiate like we know how much is 3 and 5, or how much is 5 times 7, because that kind of work is involved so often that it’s good not to be confounded by it. When you write something down, you should be able to immediately differentiate it without even thinking about it, and without making any mistakes. You’ll find you need to do this operation all the time—not only in physics, but in all the sciences. Therefore differentiation is like the arithmetic you had to learn before you could learn algebra.

Incidentally, the same goes for algebra: there’s a lot of algebra. We are assuming that you can do algebra in your sleep, upside down, without making a mistake. We know it isn’t true, so you should also practice algebra: write yourself a lot of expressions, practice them, and don’t make any errors. Errors in algebra, differentiation, and integration are only nonsense; they’re things that just annoy the physics, and annoy your mind while you’re trying to analyze something. You should be able to do calculations as quickly as possible, and with a minimum of errors. That requires nothing but rote practice—that’s the only way to do it. It’s like making yourself a multiplication table, like you did in elementary school: they’d put a bunch of numbers on the board, and you’d go: “This times that, this times that,” and so on—Bing! Bing! Bing!

---

I would even say that you can use some of the advanced problems as an OPPORTUNITY to hone your rusty "routine" skills.  For example if you do a maximization problem (not the most conceptually hard, but still a little non routine in that it is multistep and may be a "word problem") and you have the method down, but mess up a calculation.  Now, when you check your answer and recognize the mistake, DON'T just say no biggie and move on.  Instead, put the solution (or answer) away and do the problem again from scratch as if it were new.  This will quickly drill you to start NOT making so many errors and it will give you more practice in both the method and the manipulations.  And it will tend to improve your test speed.

Comment: I think not that I have problems with the basics. 
The silly mistakes I asked  about once most likely happen because of poor concentration.
Concerning the Feynman’s quote , I think that I do know differentiation like I know how much is 5 times 7, yet I make flaws in both.
The probability of me writing the derivative wrong , or a function ,whose derivative is negative , is increasing is close to that of me writing 5*7=30.However , this is not an indication of bad knowledge or absence of mastery (I wanted to say poor mastery but I don’t know if poor is a suitable collocation to mastery).

Comment: Furthermore ; because  I differentiate like I calculate 5*7 , I make mistakes. 
Because I write without thinking , I write  based on my “ (flawed) instinct” ; I make mistakes.
I’ve later discovered after long thinking and after reading the comments at the post you have mentioned , that the solution to my problem is to doubt everything, literally  everything , I ( attempt to) write .

Comment: Please note that when I write 10 pages of mathematics, the percentage of flaws I make is usually no more than 3%; however , they are still annoying and frustrating as they resemble a hindrance which prevents me from accomplishing a 100% correct work

Comment: Concerning the main subject , I am afraid it has become a disccusion as discussions within posts are frowned upon on SE (af far as I know). Would it be bad if ,among the routine exercises, some tricks or some new questions which require more thinking were inserted?Those tricks and “difficult” questions won’t cause an above average student from passing the test, they would only prevent him/her from taking a perfect score and thus would lower the percentage of perfect scores.

Comment: @Aloz371 adding one or two tricky questions which prevent a student from getting 100% is a common thing that math instructors do. I would say that as long as those tricky questions should be achievable without going too far beyond what you have explicitly taught that having a question which makes up the difference between an A and an A+ is perfectly fine. But it should not be 30% of the test, a general philosophy among Western educators is that the test should primarily describe whether a student has learned the material that has been taught not whether they have risen to the level of a master

Comment: I need to edit on my last comment; however, I am not allowed to edit on a comment after five minutes from posting it. I said :  “Those tricks and “difficult” exercises won’t cause* an above average student from passsing the test”.  I wanted to say “Those tricks and difficult exercises won’t prevent* an above  average student from passing the test.”

Comment: You can't edit after 5, but you can delete and rewrite.  (No biggie, just FYI.)

Comment: @guest I know I can delete and rewrite . However , I didn’t know if this would violate the rules of the SE community  because by the time I wanted to edit (or delete and rewrite) , someone had already replied on my original comment.